# How to set django database settings

Tags: django

I am new to django.
I need to use mysql database. I also need to specify the host, username, password..etc
I tried to change my .settings file but it is not working

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'mysql',
    'NAME': 'database',                      
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'passwd',
    'HOST': 'localhost',                      
    'PORT': '',
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its `django.db.backends.mysql` not just `mysql`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'database',                      
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'passwd',
    'HOST': 'localhost',                      
    'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is the backend module connection

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'yourdatabase',
    'USER': 'yourusername',
    'PASSWORD': 'yourpassword',
    'HOST': 'localhost',                      
    'PORT': '',
}
```